# React native ios build error: RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h file not found

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a project with ios. getting following error on build

```
node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridge.m:17:9: fatal error: 'RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h' file not found
#import "RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

versions:
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react": "17.0.2",

Answer (score 2):

**Removing the below lines** (which I believe were added from troubleshooting a different problem) from `package.json` and running `Clean Build Folder` within Xcode worked for me.

`pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules' pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'`