# Why am I getting 'RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h' file not found error when trying to build my React Native app for IOS?

Tags: react-native

When I try to build my app using either the terminal command "npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release" or from Xcode I get the following error: **'RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h' file not found**.

I have deleted the derived data folder's content, cleaned the project, and done pod disintegrate and pod setup, but I still get the same error when I try to build. I've successfully built the Android version without any problems so it must be something related to IOS configurations. Still, I don't get any other errors except from the one I mention here. Can someone please help? I have tried to do the steps mentioned here but I don't have this stuff on my package.json file:
[React native ios build error: RCTDevLoadingViewProtocol.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73513218/react-native-ios-build-error-rctdevloadingviewprotocol-h-file-not-found)